# Submit form with alternative to preventDefault

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, preventdefault

I'm struggling to get my website's sign-in functionality to work across all browsers - the closest I can get being an "ReferenceError: event is not defined" error in Firefox.

I know there's a bunch of existing posts on preventDefault being handled differently in Firefox particularly, but none of the options I've found seem to work on all browsers. Here's my basic setup...

```
<button id="signinbutton" name="signin" type="submit" onclick="signInSubmit(this.form, this.form.signInPassword);">Sign In</button>

function signInSubmit(theForm, theHashPassword) {
  event.preventDefault(); //disables submit action so I can add custom code
  //rest of sign in...
  //e.g. theForm.appendChild(p);
}
```

The reason firefox gives the error, is that I haven't explictly passed "event" from my click/submit handler (which I don't think I can do with my existing setup since I'm directly calling "signInSubmit" with other arguments).  From other posts I experimented with...

- removing event.preventDefault() and changing the button type from "submit" to "button" (but this just prevents the login working at all on all browsers because I'm passing data using this.form)
- removing event.preventDefault() and adding "return false" at the bottom of signInSubmit() - this has the same problem to the above also
- the most promising suggestion was to remove the onclick attribute from my button and implement something like...

  `$('#signInForm').submit(function(e) {
    if(!ready){
        e.preventDefault();
        signInSubmit(this.form, this.form.signInPassword, false);
    }
  });`

But of course from the context of a jquery selection .submit(), I can't use "this.form" to refer to my original form, and neither can have I been able to return the form in the format expected by signInSubmit with `$('#signInForm')" or "$('#signInForm').serialize()`.

Apologies if that's all a rather messy collection of thoughts on this issue, but I'm really hoping someone notices something in my setup that could be re-worked to get around this - thanks for any thoughts at all!

Comment: Do not use click events to control form submission. Use the submit event. Otherwise keyboard submission will bypass your code!

Comment: Please provide a sample of your output HTML so that a mockup will be accurate :)

Comment: Ok, so in other words remove the onclick entirely - but that's a general security suggestion versus something that's going to fix my issue right?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Ya for consistency better is to use submit event of `form` but that's said, the submit event of form would trigger click event of first submit button on all 'modern' browsers, cannot just find the spec (if any?!) actually: http://jsfiddle.net/o7j3o86v/

Comment: @A.Wolf... exactly *which* button will it `click` if there are multiple submit buttons? :) (the first as it happens... but roll on removal of all old browsers)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I finally find it in [HTML5 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#implicit-submission)  That's said, i'm still agree would have better to explecitely bound the submit event to the `form` because ya, it is still depending of own browser implementation to fire or not *implicit form submission*

Comment: @A.Wolff: Yep. HTML`5` being the issue. Roll on the death of HTML4 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the most promising suggestion was to remove the onclick attribute from my button and implement something like

Yes. Do that.

> I can't use "this.form" to refer to my original form

That is because the event is firing in the context of the form instead of the submit button. Use `this` instead of `this.form`.

> ```
>  $('#signInForm')" or "$('#signInForm').serialize()
> ```

The original function expects a DOM object representing the form. The first of those is a jQuery wrapper around such an object, the second of those is a string of URL encoded data from the form.

If you were going to use that approach (which you shouldn't since `this` is more elegant) then you would use `$('#signInForm')[0]` to extract the DOM object from the jQuery object.